# Checkbox envia 'on' ao ser serializado

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Tenho um formulário html que envio os dados via ajax assim:

```
function showValues() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/Home/salvaItem",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      $("#results").text(data);
    }
  });

  return false;
}
```

Tudo ocorre bem, porém, tenho 3 campos que são checkbox onde estou esperando o valor 1 ou 0 para tratar, e o mesmo está sendo enviado 'on' ou não envia.

Já tentei fazer assim `<input type="checkbox" name="delivery" checked="1"> Entrega a domicílio` pra ver se força o mesmo a enviar o número 1, mas sem sucesso.

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi usando:

`<input type="checkbox" name="delivery" value="1">`